# Can't access wireless network after modify /etc/network/interfaces - Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: networking, network-manager, 15.10

I have just installed Ubuntu 15.10 on my PC and I want to reconfigure network interfaces. I added `/etc/network/interfaces` file as follows:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.4
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1
```

However, after change, I restart network-manager service, my network interfaces not working:

[image: picture's link]

But when I delete the above script, everything is fine. Anyone have problems like me?

PS: I can't also find `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`. Where is it?

Comment: That's how Network Manager is intended to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection managing tool used by ubuntu is `network-manager`. If you edit your `/etc/network/interfaces` file you're going to disable network-manager for this interface. The result is it will not be shown.

You can use `nmcli -d` to show if they are managed or not:

```
$ nmcli -d
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION 
wlp4s0  wifi      connected  YOUR-SSID   #Managed
wlp5s0  wifi      unmanaged  --          #Not managed
enp3s0  ethernet  unmanaged  --         
lo      loopback  unmanaged  --
```

## Solution 1

You can remove the lines again and restart the system. Then use `network-manager` cmd-line tools `nmcli` or the gui shown in your screenshot to configure the network connections.

`Edit Connections -> SSID -> Edit -> IPv4 Settings -> Manual -> Add address`

## Solution 2

Or don't remove these lines and use `wpa_supplicant` and `wpa_client` to connect and manage the connection yourself in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Comment: No problem. Please mark the answer if it was the solution to your problem.